# Remove everything from the page and replace it with the unity game onclick

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function, unity-game-engine

The title is self-explanatory. I'm attempting to conceal a hidden href that, when clicked, erases everything on the page, leaving it blank for a second before inserting the unity game as the whole page.

Here's what I've got so far.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script>
    function wipeHTML() {
      document.documentElement.innerHTML = nothing; //NEED HELP HERE
      then wait 1 second
      document.documentElement.innerHTML = unity game loads; //NEED HELP HERE
    }

  </script>
  <!-- UNITY STUFF -->

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="TemplateData/style.css">
    <script src="TemplateData/UnityProgress.js"></script>
    <script src="TemplateData/unityloader41.js"></script>
    <script>
      var gameInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("gameContainer", "Build/slope.json", {
        onProgress: UnityProgress,
        Module: {
          onRuntimeInitialized: function() {
            UnityProgress(gameInstance, "complete")
          }
        }
      });

    </script>
  </head>

  <body style="margin: 0; overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="webgl-content">
      <div id="gameContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0;"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <!-- UNITY STUFF END -->
  <h1>
    <a href="javascript:wipeHTML">wipe everything</a>
  </h1>
  <div>
    <h1>
      hello
    </h1>
    <h3>
      erase me
    </h3>
  </div>
```

Tell me what I'm doing wrong! ‍♂️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clear the body of the page:

```
document.body = document.createElement("body");
```

To show the game, add a timeout, replace the console.log with the code to show the game.

```
setTimeout(() => console.log("load unity here"), 5e3)
```